# Javascript function to toggle all tags in a classes not executing

Tags: javascript

I am trying to toggle classes using Javascript which runs on a template generated by Django. I have the following code:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    document.querySelectorAll('.cat').forEach(category => {
        category_id = category.getAttribute('id').slice(1,);
        var toggle_class_name = `child-of-${category_id}`;
        category.addEventListener('click', () => toggle_class(toggle_class_name));
    });
});

function toggle_class(toggle_class_name) {
    console.log(toggle_class_name);
    document.querySelectorAll(toggle_class_name).forEach(item => {
        console.log('loop triggered');
        var current_display = item.style.display;
        
        if (current_display === 'none') {
            current_display = 'block';
            console.log(`expanding`);
        }
    
        else {
            current_display = 'none';
            console.log(`collapsing`);
        }
        
        item.style.display = current_display;
    });
};
```

```html
<div>
    <table class='table'>
        <tr>
            <th class='ref-col'>Reference</th>
            <th class='des-col'>Description</th>
            
                <th class='mth-head'>Jun-20</th>    
            
                <th class='mth-head'>Jul-20</th>    
            
                <th class='mth-head'>Aug-20</th>    
            
        </tr>
        
            <tr id='c2' class='child-of-None cat'>
                <td class='ref-col'>C0002</td>
                <td class='des-col'>Financial Statements</td>
                
                    <td class='amt-col'></td>
                
                    <td class='amt-col'></td>
                
                    <td class='amt-col'></td>
                
            </tr>
        
            <tr id='c1' class='child-of-2 cat'>
                <td class='ref-col'>C0001</td>
                <td class='des-col'>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspBalance Sheet</td>
                
                    <td class='amt-col'></td>
                
                    <td class='amt-col'></td>
                
                    <td class='amt-col'></td>
                
            </tr>
        
            <tr id='c6' class='child-of-1 cat'>
                <td class='ref-col'>C0006</td>
                <td class='des-col'>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspNon-Current Assets</td>
                
                    <td class='amt-col'></td>
                
                    <td class='amt-col'></td>
                
                    <td class='amt-col'></td>
                
            </tr>
        
            <tr id='c11' class='child-of-6 cat'>
                <td class='ref-col'>C0011</td>
                <td class='des-col'>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspProperty, Plant &amp; Equipment</td>
                
                    <td class='amt-col'></td>
                
                    <td class='amt-col'></td>
                
                    <td class='amt-col'></td>
                
            </tr>
        
            <tr id='g1000001' class='child-of-11 gl'>
                <td class='ref-col'>1000001</td>
                <td class='des-col'>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspFreehold Land</td>
                
                    <td class='amt-col'></td>
                
                    <td class='amt-col'></td>
                
                    <td class='amt-col'></td>
                
            </tr>
   </table>
```

The toggle_class function does get triggered as the toggle_class_name gets correctly logged onto the console. However none of the other things get logged onto the console.
The tags in the DOM which are of the class 'toggle_class_name' do not get toggled when I click the 'category'.
These tags have additional classes other than 'toogle_class_name' as well.

Why are the classes not getting toggled?

Comment: you seem to be updating the variable `current_display` but not assigning it back to the DOM element - as in `item.style.display = current_display;` at the end of the `if/else`

Comment: Just tried it. Didn't work. The console should at least log "expanding" or "collapsing".

And my understanding was that current_display refers to the actual tag and not a copy of it. Please correct me if I am wrong. I am new to this.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Please [edit] you question to include a [mcve]. Otherwise, it might take a lot more time and a heap of guessing to figure *exactly* where the issue lies.  (What does your HTML look like?)

Comment: I just noticed this: `.slice(1, );` - I think this is a syntax error. It should be `.slice(1);` (no comma)

Comment: Nope. nothing :(

Comment: Added a working example. Probably a noob mistake.

Comment: Your second selector is missing the dot `.` for the class name - so change this line to include it like:  `var toggle_class_name = '.child-of-${category_id}';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several issues in your code:

1. `.slice(1, );` - I think this is a syntax error. It should be `.slice(1);` (no comma)
2. A selector is missing the dot `.` for the class name - so change this line to include it like: `var toggle_class_name = '.child-of-${category_id}';`
3. Instead of adding removing properties manually, it's likely best to toggle classes with the desired properties

**See working demo below:**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  document.querySelectorAll('.cat').forEach(category => {
    category_id = category.getAttribute('id').slice(1);
    var toggle_class_name = `.child-of-${category_id}`;
    category.addEventListener('click', () => toggle_class(toggle_class_name));
  });
});

function toggle_class(toggle_class_name) {
  console.log(toggle_class_name);
  document.querySelectorAll(toggle_class_name).forEach(item => {
    item.classList.toggle('hidden');
  });
};
```

```css
tr.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class='table' border=1>
    <tr>
      <th class='ref-col'>Reference</th>
      <th class='des-col'>Description</th>
      <th class='mth-head'>Jun-20</th>
      <th class='mth-head'>Jul-20</th>
      <th class='mth-head'>Aug-20</th>
    </tr>

    <tr id='c2' class='child-of-None cat'>
      <td class='ref-col'>C0002</td>
      <td class='des-col'>Financial Statements</td>
      <td class='amt-col'></td>
      <td class='amt-col'></td>
      <td class='amt-col'></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id='c1' class='child-of-2 cat'>
      <td class='ref-col'>C0001</td>
      <td class='des-col'>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspBalance Sheet</td>
      <td class='amt-col'></td>
      <td class='amt-col'></td>
      <td class='amt-col'></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id='c6' class='child-of-1 cat'>
      <td class='ref-col'>C0006</td>
      <td class='des-col'>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspNon-Current Assets</td>
      <td class='amt-col'></td>
      <td class='amt-col'></td>
      <td class='amt-col'></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id='c11' class='child-of-6 cat'>
      <td class='ref-col'>C0011</td>
      <td class='des-col'>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspProperty, Plant &amp; Equipment</td>
      <td class='amt-col'></td>
      <td class='amt-col'></td>
      <td class='amt-col'></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id='g1000001' class='child-of-11 gl'>
      <td class='ref-col'>1000001</td>
      <td class='des-col'>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspFreehold Land</td>
      <td class='amt-col'></td>
      <td class='amt-col'></td>
      <td class='amt-col'></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```